# subverting adblock detection?

Tags: javascript

Several questions concern how to detect adblock use, but I couldn't find any that explained how to **subvert** detection?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this thing?

Comment: Do you mean as a user (such as a GreaseMonkey script in FF)?

Comment: The only way to *subvert* detection is to *emulate* what is being detected.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - yes, I would like to use adblock without the sites I visit (easily) knowing I use adblock.

Comment: Just wondering, but why not just whitelist them?

Comment: Test is basically checking to see if an element is visible or loaded.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - it's not them personally, that's just the first time I've encountered detection, and naturally wondered if their was a countermeasure.

Comment: I would just say consider allowing the ads to load, if you care about the site.

Comment: I'll add that a lot of this ad-blocking detection is done with Javascript, usually a function that's loaded from an external .js file.  How they work is by analyizing various components of elements containing ads.  If the elements have been altered in any way, it assumes there's an ad blocker.  Blocking certain .js files has always ended up in me being able to evade adblock detection so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't find it appropriate to bypass ad blocking detection, though I know that others may have different viewpoints.  If a site doesn't want to offer you their content without you displaying their ads (perhaps their only way of paying for the site), then that seems to me to be their prerogative and if they go to the trouble of detecting the ad blocking, then it seems that that is their right.

That said, there are a number of different ways that they could be detecting that you're blocking their ads.  Some could be complicated enough that you couldn't simulate that you had the ads when you didn't.  For example, if you are blocking flash and they are trying to communicate with a flash object to verify that it's there, you'd have to simulate that it was really there and that could be quite difficult.  If their detection logic was a lot simpler, then it might be possible to fool it with some sort of simulation.  But, I suspect this would just be an arms race and if any significant number of folks foiled their blocking detection, they'd just make it more sophisticated.

In that case, all you could do it try to figure out how to patch their actual javascript detection code directly to make it return a false answer.  How you would do that would vary from one site to the next and any solution would have to be coded for a specific site.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I use AdBlock (and have for years), and although I appreciate that it helps pages load faster and more successfully, there are some sites I willfully whitelist ([Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/), for example). Sites that I trust and enjoy. But honestly, I hardly ever (actually, ever?) click ads, so other than display, not sure it helps much. But for a few sites, I'll suffer the visual distraction.

Comment: My point is that it's not really your decision to make.  It's the web-site owner's decision to withhold the web-site if you won't display their ads.  You can argue that you never do anything with ads you see, but ads pay for a lot of the internet so the model is working for a lot of sites.  If a lot of people blocked ads, then we'd have a very different internet.

Comment: If I'm requesting it, I have control (as far as that goes), not the site admin (we won't even get into iOS). I see what I want and what I choose to view, not the content/display owner. If the content owner goes out of business and I no longer have that opportunity, than I have shot myself in the foot. Hence, my note of caution.

Comment: Note, it is my firm belief that the *vast* majority of users will never be sophisticated enough to successfully user an adblocker.

Comment: This will be my last post on the ethics of ad blocking as I don't really intend to debate that here.  My point was that the site owner decides what to offer you and whether they want to offer it to you for free with ads, offer it free without ads or require direct payment for use of the site.  Once the site owner sets their policy, you can then decide if you want to use their site under those terms.  When you block ads, you are trying to change the terms to something other than the site owner chose and I think they have every right to detect that and block your access to the site.

Comment: I think that we are probably more in agreement than disagreement. I understand your position (which is content-creator-oriented, or at least content-owner-payee oriented). The main difference is the reality and practice of control, and I do think I will not cede control that I do not agree with (either actively or impassively). There is a hard and a soft approach; I happen to advocate a soft, potentially nuanced approach, whereby you seem to favor a hard, direct approach. You are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @jfriend00 - under your logic, if I pick up a free magazine and rip out all the ads, the magazine publisher has the right to come and take the magazine away from me, and you would support that.

Comment: @Andrew Health.  That's not the same.  I never said the publisher had the right to come take something back from you that you already possessed.   That isn't analagous to a web-site.  But, I would say that the publisher has the right to stop offering the free magazine in neighborhoods that promote removing the ads before distribution or stop sending you the free magazine if they determine that you aren't a desired reader.